# How do I set properties for different icon layers using file_ico_save in Python-Fu?

Tags: gimp, python-fu

I'm using the following code to successfully create an icon with Python-Fu in GIMP:

```py
pdb.gimp_palette_set_background('green')
image = pdb.gimp_image_new(256, 256, RGB)
image.new_layer(pos=1, fill_mode = BACKGROUND_FILL)
fileName = 'C:\\favicon.ico'
pdb.file_ico_save(image, None, fileName, fileName)
pdb.gimp_image_delete(image)
```

When I export an image as `.ico` manually, I can set different properties like compression, bpp, alpha-bits, color palette etc. Per default, the largest layer will be saved using compression, which is not recommended. Manually, I can uncheck compression. But saving an icon programmatically with `pdb.file_ico_save` does not offer those settings.

So how can I set different properties of the icon layers, when saving the icon with `pdb.file_ico_save`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To judge from what I think is the source code: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/blob/gimp-2-10/plug-ins/file-ico/ico-save.c
uou can't control those parameters. It looks like the code tries to make intelligent guesses as to the correct values to use, for example compression if the width|height is greater than 255

Comment: The source code cannot lie, I guess, thanks for looking it up! It looks like it is time for `file_ico_save2`, like they did with `file_png_save2` to add more parameters. Are you a GIMP dev by any chance? :)

Comment: Not, not a GIMP dev. If you want to request a fix for this: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues